# Algorithm for reducing 2D list to its unique elements, maintaining order

Tags: python, algorithm

Input:

`[[102, 106], [106, 107], [101, 106], [104, 105, 106], [105], [103, 105], [104]]`

Desired output:

`[102, 107, 101, 106, 105, 103, 104]`

Each index of the original array is essentially the list of possibilities for the index in the result array. The goal being to represent each number one time in the result array. I'm having difficulty finding an appropriate type of algorithm for this task. What general approach would one take to a problem of this type?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with uniquely? I find the question a bit vague as it is now ...

Comment: Every number should appear in the final list, and every index can be chosen from the original array located in the same index.

Comment: Ah, so you are basically looking for a solver for a 1D Sudoku puzzle, where the array gives all the allowed numbers for a given position, and every number can only appear at 1 position?

Comment: Precisely, the main problem I've been having is simply articulating it so far

Comment: Ah, that was not immediately clear to me. There are plenty of sites explaining how to write a solver for those. My favorite one is the essay 'Solving every sudoku' by Peter Norvig, but his website seems to have disappeared ...

Comment: You may want to look at the bipartite matching problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#In_unweighted_bipartite_graphs) and the Hopcroft-Karp algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) if your original array size is >= 30 (excluding 0- and 1-possibility items).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple solution that just uses length of the `set` of all the solutions as a key to `max`:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> data = [[102, 106], [106, 107], [101, 106], [104, 105, 106], [105], [103, 105], [104]]
>>> max(it.product(*data), key=lambda x: len(set(x)))
(102, 107, 101, 106, 105, 103, 104)
```

Comment: I liked it. Nice usage of lambda

Comment: This is super clever and worked for my purposes. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `unique_everseen` after you have flattened the list:

```
# sample input
data = [[102, 106], [106, 107], [101, 106], [104, 105, 106], [105], [103, 105], [104]]

from  more_itertools import unique_everseen
data = list(unique_everseen([a for sub in data for a in sub]))
```

Comment: Note: `more_itertools` is needed to be installed explicitly using `pip`